# Migrating from Surround SCM to Perforce

Tags: version-control, import, perforce, migrate, surroundscm

So we have our whole work based in SSCM right now with a lot of history and versions etc.  And want to move everything to Perforce.

Are there any good resources out there (I tried looking but couldn't find any) which could help me do this?

If not I was thinking of a python script to check out everything from SSCM and then put it to perforce. Anyone with this sort of experience have any thoughts to share?

Will it be doable to shift all history, comments and versions to Perforce?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's doable, but it looks like you're on your own.  Perforce has some [migration tools](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/migration-conversion) available for various SCM systems, but alas Surround is not one of them.  You might be able to use one of these as a starting point though.  I have migrated a VSS repository using the script they have available and it worked great.

Comment: Yea that's what I figured. I've written one in python which is about 90% done. Need to fix some bugs with comments transferring over and whatnot. It wasn't fun but oh well, it's something you do once. Thanks though

Comment: @Joiya550: When you get it working, you should contact Perforce and have them add it to their set of migration tools.  As I recall, The VSS migration script was created by a user, not Perforce Software, but they do support it.

Comment: @Joiya550 if you did generate this, even if you didn't push it to Perforce, it would be an excellent item to add to Github or a Gist.

Comment: It was part of my internship so I cannot upload it publicly :)